# How to avoid ImprovedNamingStrategy in joinTable in Grails

Tags: grails-orm, grails-2.0

I have a legacy database which I can't change and I have this setup

```
class Foo {

    static hasMany = [bars:Bar]

    static mapping = {
    version false

    columns {
        id column: "FooId"
        color column: "FooColor"

        bars joinTable: [name: "FooBar", key: 'FooId', column: 'BarId']
    }

    transient
    def getBarName(){
       ((Bar)this.bars.toArray()[0]).name
    }
 }

class Bar {

    static hasMany = [foos:Foo]

    static belongsTo = [Foo, Baz]

    static mapping = {
    version false

    columns {
        id column: "BarId"
        name column: "BarName"
    }
 }
```

When i try to access the method getBarName() in a controller Hibernate translates the inverse column name to "bar_id". Is there some way to set up a mapping like the one for the id and property columns?

And on a side note. How do i correctly implement getBarName()? Thacan't possibly be the correct implementation...

****EDIT****
**----------------------------------------------------------------------**
Apparently I was unclear above. The thing is that i already have a join column which has the form

```
-------------------
|RowId|FooId|BarId|
-------------------
|  1  | abc | 123 |
-------------------
```

**Benoit's** answer isn't really applicable in this situation since I want to avoid having a domain object for the joinTable.

****EDIT 2****
**----------------------------------------------------------------------**
Solved it. Dont understand it though... But split the join table information between the two domain classes and it works...

```
class Foo {

    static hasMany = [bars:Bar]

    static mapping = {
    version false

    columns {
        id column: "FooId"
        color column: "FooColor"

        bars joinTable: [name: "FooBar", key: 'FooId']
    }

    transient
    def getBarName(){
       ((Bar)this.bars.toArray()[0]).name
    }
 }

class Bar {

static hasMany = [foos:Foo]

    static belongsTo = [Foo, Baz]

    static mapping = {
    version false

    columns {
        id column: "BarId"
        name column: "BarName"

        bars joinTable: [name: "FooBar", key: 'BarId']
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation [Many-to-One/One-to-One Mappings and One-to-Many Mapping](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#ormdsl) :

> With a bidirectional one-to-many you can change the foreign key column
>   used by changing the column name on the many side of the association
>   as per the example in the previous section on one-to-one associations.
>   However, with unidirectional associations the foreign key needs to be
>   specified on the association itself.

Thye given example is:

```
class Person {
String firstName
static hasMany = [addresses: Address]
static mapping = {
        table 'people'
        firstName column: 'First_Name'
        addresses column: 'Person_Address_Id'
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. See the edit for clarification